# How to use a SQL variable and iterate through unique values?

Tags: sql, variables, case, presto

I've been searching for a way to iterate through unique values of a column in a case statement. I won't know what the unique values will be. Something like this.

`CASE WHEN (distinct value for car_model) THEN (SELECT sum(buyers) FROM table WHERE car_model NOT IN distinct value for car_model)`

I want the case statement to go through all of the distinct values for car_model. For some reason, I can't figure out how to do this. I don't know the syntax to make sure that the distinct value in the WHEN is the same value in my WHERE clause.

Table

`+-----------+---------+--------+`
`| car_model |  sales  | buyers |`
`+-----------+---------+--------+`
`| rav4      | 100,000 |      5 |`
`| rav4      | 15,000  |      1 |`
`| cc        | 20,000  |      1 |`
`| navigator | 30,000  |      1 |`
`| cc        | 17,000  |      1 |`
`| q5        | 78,000  |      3 |`
`+-----------+---------+--------+`

Desired result

`+-----------+--------+`
`| car_model | buyers |`
`+-----------+--------+`
`| rav4      |      6 |`
`| cc        |     10 |`
`| navigator |     11 |`
`| q5        |      9 |`
`+-----------+--------+`

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help understanding your question better.

Comment: @GMB thanks. I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? The "desired result" you posted doesn't seem to make sense - why are there 11 buyers for "navigator" when there's only 1 in the table?

Comment: @NathanGriffiths I'm looking for the total excluding whatever the line item is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work:
**untested**

```
select t.car_model, (select sum(buyers) from table) - sum(t.buyers) buyers
from table t
group by t.car_model
```

This takes the total sum of all buyers and subtracts the sum of buyers for the current row's car_model.

Answer (score 0):

To get "the total excluding whatever the line item [total] is" (as you mentioned in the comments) you need to sum up all buyers for all models to get total buyers, then sum up the buyers for each individual model and subtract it from the total buyers. Here's one way of doing that using CROSS JOIN:

```
SELECT 
     c.car_model
   , t.total_buyers - SUM(c.buyers) AS total_buyers_minus_buyers_for_this_model
FROM Table c
CROSS JOIN 
   (SELECT SUM(buyers) AS total_buyers FROM Table) t
GROUP BY 
   c.car_model
```

See [example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98becc/2/0).